# Read text file for Countdown

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a text file on the server with the following text:

```
user1 2020-01-01 19:45:51
```

I want to retrieve Countdown start time from a text file stored on the server. Using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="countdown"></div>
    <script>
      function countdownTimer() {
        const difference = +new Date("2020-01-01") - +new Date();
        let remaining = "Time's up!";

        if (difference > 0) {
          const parts = {
            days: Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
            hours: Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24),
            minutes: Math.floor((difference / 1000 / 60) % 60),
            seconds: Math.floor((difference / 1000) % 60)
          };

          remaining = Object.keys(parts)
            .map(part => {
              if (!parts[part]) return;
              return `${parts[part]} ${part}`;
            })
            .join(" ");
        }

        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = remaining;
      }

      countdownTimer();
      setInterval(countdownTimer, 1000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can JavaScript read start time from a text file on the server?

Comment: You already tagged this with `PHP`, do you have any code available?

Comment: Try to make an ajax call to the text file and then you can read its content with response.body.
refer https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_first